# Different types in C# Interface Implementation

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, interface

I really struggle entitling this, but i'll try my best at explaining my point.

Say i have this :

```
    List<IShape> Shapes = new List<IShape>();

    public interface IShape {
       dynamic shapeAttributes { get; set; }
    };

    public struct SquareAttributes {
      float sizeOfSide;
    };

    public struct CircleAttributes {
      float radius
    };
    
    public class Square : IShape {
      SquareAttributes shapeAttributes { get; set; }
    };

    public class Circle : IShape {
      CircleAttributes shapeAttributes { get; set; }
    };

    Shapes.Add(new Square());
    Shapes.Add(new Circle());
```

How Do I make that situation work ? Here the "dynamic" keyword in IShape is not resolved when implemented in Square and Circle, but I'd still want to be able to define the right Type when implementing rather than using "dynamic" everywhere. Is there a right way to deal with this, with the ability re regroup all kind of Shapes in the same list? I hope this is clear.

I obviously simplified the whole thing to get straight to the point, but everything involved is far more complex and cannot really be fitted into a single large piece.

Comment: `public interface IShape<T> { T shapeAttributes {get;set;} }`

Comment: Dynamic isn’t really for that. Also having an attributes class for something like this is confusing

Comment: That's a good start but I can't unify the List that way

Comment: How can something use "shape attributes" of an `IShape` if they do not really know what attributes the shape will have?

Comment: @DanielA.White When I put it that way i guess it doesn't really make much sense, but the overall problem is that i'd like to be able to have a List of different types that share all the same properties but one. That's the reason why I tried with the dynamic in the first place, but i'd rather not use it right.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're pointing at the very problem. Maybe my way of looking at it is not right but I really want to unify different types in a single list, thats the whole point like i said upper.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I'd the take elements from the list and Discriminate base on the type of shape (that's supposed to be registered as an enum in the IShape in the first place). Am I clear enough ?

Comment: For now i'll just shove every parameters in the same struct and access them depending on the context.

Comment: Probably an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). It seems you've attempted a solution, but it's unclear what the problem you're trying to solve is. Why do they all need to be in the same list and how do you plan to use it?

Comment: @CrimsonFreak Suppose you are able to store them in the same list. How are you going to consume that list? If you `for()` it, what single expression will you write after the `Shapes[i].shapeAttributes.`?

Comment: @Xerillio That's kind of it. But as I thought this was gonna be a solution, I've already refactor much of my code to fit that approach. Anyway it looks like someone has a convenient solution

Comment: @GSerg In fact I've thought of that approach because the parameters won't often be used outside of the class. But I wanted a solution for when i have to access it outside, and I already planned a way to discriminate the Type based on the context, which is not really elegant, but sufficient for the little I was gonna use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your shapes attributes very different you can use `System.Object` as common type. But don't forget to check if you pass correct `ShapeAttributes` type to correct implementation of `IShape`, so I recommend to use set method instead of property setter:

Objects definition:

---

```
public interface IShape
{
    object ShapeAttributes { get;  }
    Type ShapeAttributesType { get; }
    void SetAttributes(object shapeAttributes);
}

public class Square : IShape
{
    public object ShapeAttributes { get; private set; }
    public Type ShapeAttributesType => typeof(SquareAttributes);     
    public void SetAttributes(object shapeAttributes)
    {
        // Check if passed correct type
        if (shapeAttributes.GetType() != ShapeAttributesType)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Argument type must be {ShapeAttributesType.FullName}", nameof(shapeAttributes));
        ShapeAttributes = shapeAttributes;
    }
}

public class Circle : IShape
{
    public object ShapeAttributes { get; private set; }
    public Type ShapeAttributesType => typeof(CircleAttributes);        
    public void SetAttributes(object shapeAttributes)
    {
        // Check if passed correct type
        if (shapeAttributes.GetType() != ShapeAttributesType)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Argument type must be {ShapeAttributesType.FullName}", nameof(shapeAttributes));
        ShapeAttributes = shapeAttributes;
    }
}

public struct SquareAttributes
{
    public float SizeOfSide { get; set; }
}

public struct CircleAttributes
{
    public float Radius { get; set; }
}
```

Usage example:

---

```
List<IShape> shapes = new List<IShape>();
var square = new Square();
square.SetAttributes(new SquareAttributes()
{
    SizeOfSide = 4.1f
});

var circle = new Circle();
circle.SetAttributes(new CircleAttributes()
{
    Radius = 2.12f
});

shapes.Add(square);
shapes.Add(circle);

foreach (var shape in shapes)
{
    //Cast ShapeAttributes based on owner class type
    switch (shape)
    {
        case Square s:
            var size = ((SquareAttributes)s.ShapeAttributes).SizeOfSide;
            Console.WriteLine($"Square.ShapeAttributes.SizeOfSide = {size}");
            break;
        case Circle c:
            var radius = ((CircleAttributes)c.ShapeAttributes).Radius;
            Console.WriteLine($"Circle.ShapeAttributes.Radius = {radius}");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks really much like it. I'm going to give that a go.
I tried passing it as "object" before but i was struggling when trying to retrieve the actual type of the shape. It really much looks like your solution solves that problem, thanks.

Comment: If you're just going to check for and cast every single shape before using it you're not getting anything out of the interface, or the generalized abstractions around attributes.  If you're going to do that you might as well just have a circle and square class each with a radius or length property.  This is just adding a ton of work and code for no benefits.

Comment: @Servy I do need the Interface for general purpose, but in very specific situation I need these parameters to be accessible outside of the class. And the overload of code that comes with it is really a good deal compared to what i'd have had to do otherwise.

Comment: @CrimsonFreak But the code as is *doesn't* allow for general purpose usage through the interface.  It *requires* casting to the known implementation for it to function, defeating the purpose of it's existence.  You could *make* a generalization that could be used without knowing the specific type, depending on how it's used and what you need it to do, but as you haven't stated what those uses are, it precludes providing a solution.  The code to do what this is doing without the interface is *simpler*, not more complex.

Comment: @Servy I've been trying my best to avoid this situation. To try and make it clearer, that particular program has 3 different processes, which each has a dedicated method in the interface, plus several variables that are generic. The only thing that is added for each inherited classes are the parameters, thus the struct for each one of them. The focus of my work lately has been to try and keep the usage of the struct a private way. But there still was situations were I didn't really manage to, thus my question in the first place.

Comment: However, now that i've tried Andrii's solution, I have a better overall view of the whole thing, and I might in the end find the way to get rid of the object Attributes in the interface to keep it to the inherited class, which has been the very point I was struggling about.

Comment: @CrimsonFreak It seems like you're trying as hard as possible *to* use this solution.   You seem to be making no attempts to avoid it at all, and you're intentionally being *super* vague about what you're actually trying to do.  Saying you have 3 different processes, and that you have variables, etc. are all just so vague as to be completely meaningless.  *Show us what you're actually doing* with this if you want any half way decent answers.  As it is you seem to be trying your best to ensure no one can provide an actual solution.

Comment: @CrimsonFreak But if you think this answer suits you, then you should remove the interface, remove all of the generalized code, and just have different classes with their own named properties for their inherent attributes, because that's much simpler and easier than this, and just as useful for your application.  If you actually *do* have some problem that requires generalizing these things together and acting on shapes irrespective of what specific shape they are, *you need to actually describe what you're doing with them* if you want help doing that.

Comment: @Servy Ok i'll provide my actual code, but it's quite a chunk